# How to query a currency in binance?

Tags: json, python-3.x, cryptocurrency

How to query a currency in binance? In the bitfinex API I can only filter BTCUSD, but in binance the query returns all negotiated pairs.

```
import requests
import json
requisicao = requests.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price')
cotacao = json.loads(requisicao.text)



def bitfinex_btc(): 
    bitFinexTick1 = requests.get("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/ticker/btcusd")
    return bitFinexTick1.json()['last_price']

bitfinexlivebtc = float(bitfinex_btc())

print ('BITFINEX BTC = U$',bitfinexlivebtc)
print ('BINANCE BTC = U$',cotacao)
```

Comment: Batch request: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=["ETHUSDT","SOLUSDT"]`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter on BTC->USD only when accessing Binance.

From the API documentation at:

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#symbol-price-ticker

you can add the symbol as a query parameter, so it would look like this:

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT

The response is of the following form:

```
{
    "price": "8196.79000000",
    "symbol": "BTCUSDT"
}
```

so in Python the function would be something like:

```
def binance_btc(): 
    binanceTick1 = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT")
    return binanceTick1.json()['price']
```

Comment: No problem @MarcusJunior! If this works for you, you can mark it as answered.

Comment: Great explanation - can i also add the period in the URL e.g 24hr or all

Comment: @Screwtape007 for the last 24 hours you have    'GET /api/v3/ticker/24hr' (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#24hr-ticker-price-change-statistics), but I'm not sure about a longer period than that. Take a look at https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md more generally for an idea of what's available.

Comment: I did a quick seacrch for "year',"1yr","all","history" i dont find anything on your provided link